# Dotnet command not recognized after reboot Raspbian

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to run my asp.net core application on Rasbpian buster OS on raspberry pi 3 B after reboot, but dotnet commad not recognized after reboot, and I face with this error [dotnet: command not found].

After I run these two lines of code on terminal the dotnet command can run correctly.

```
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet 
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet
```

You can see screenshot of my SSH connection through Putty to raspberry pi after reboot.

[image]

Comment: Exports are the right way to go here but when you call `export var=something`, then that will only apply to the *current* shell session. So it is not a global configuration and especially not something that will stick after reboot. In order to achieve that, you will have to add those lines to your shell profile, e.g. `.profile` or `.bashrc`, which are scripts that automatically run when a shell session starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PATH` is a `:`-seperated list of every directory where files should be executable by just writing the name of the file in the command line. (You still need the `x` permission)

`dotnet` is not in your `PATH`.

The command `export PATH=...` changes the `PATH` for your current session.

If you want to have dotnet everytime on startup, create a symlink from `/usr/bin/dotnet` to `$HOME/dotnet/dotnet`:

```
sudo ln -s "$HOME/dotnet/dotnet" "/usr/bin/dotnet"
```

or add copy the command to the bottom of the `$HOME/.bashrc` file.

[**NOTE**]

If you don't have dotnet installed on `$HOME/dotnet/`, you will need to change that directory in the `ln` command

Comment: Dear dan1st thank you, my problem was solved, but I want to run my asp.net core application after raspberry pi boot, how can start my website in startup?

Comment: If my answer helped you, I would appreciate you accepting it. Running the application on startup is an entirely different question. [This](https://carlos.mendible.com/2017/03/26/raspberry-pi-run-aspnet-core-on-startup/) may help you with that question.

Comment: I want to run my asp.net core application as startup in Linux your link is about Windows 10 Iot core running startup

Comment: Sorry, my fault. What about [this](https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/04/17/hosting-an-asp-net-core-2-application-on-a-raspberry-pi/)? The `Run the app as a service`
chapter seems right.

Comment: Thanks dan, I found the solution with call executable file using `crontab -e` on @reboot

Comment: Hi, It didnt worked for me. my path was `sudo ln -s "/usr/share/dotnet/" "/usr/bin/dotnet/"`. Any suggestion.

Comment: @Vara in the OP's question, it was `$HOME/dotnet/dotnet`. It's just installed at another location.

Comment: Hi @dan1st thank You for response. I had installed in shared folder. Changed path accordingly

Comment: @Vara I've added this to my answer.

Comment: @dan1st thank You. `sudo ln -s "/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet" "/usr/bin/dotnet"`